# Is it let or const for useHistory and useLocation in React Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I am using React Router for my application, and when I see guides online people are using both let and const for useHistory and useLocation Hooks.

What is the right declaration for these Hooks and why?

```
let history = useHistory();
let location = useLocation();
```

or

```
const history = useHistory();
const location = useLocation();
```

Comment: It kinda does. But why is documentation of React-Router showing let? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: Document is written by humans, and it's kind of opinion-based.

Comment: Cool, I accepted your similar question as it has the answer i wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality is the same. using const is basically just making the variable strict. 
Making it strict stop yourself from potentially overriding the variable in the future.

Is this the answer you were looking for?